# Weird dynamic linker issue under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, libtorrent

I'm not an experienced `Linux` developer (my primary platform is `Windows`).

I have a dynamically loading `.so` module (let's call it module `A`) which is statically linked with `Libtorrent 1.2.15`.

I compiled `Libtorrent` with `OpenSSL 1.1.1g` (which was previously built by me too).

Now, a weird issue. **Two different cases**:

1. If I compile `A` with just specifying paths to my `OpenSSL` headers and libs and NOT specifying exact library files - all is working fine! Module is compiled OK, loaded OK, works OK.

I.e. , in my `Qt` project this looks so:

```
LIBS += -Lpath_to_my_openssl/prebuilt/linux/lib
```

2. If I compile `A` with also specifying the exact library files - it's compiled OK, loaded OK (I can parse torrents using this loaded module), but crashes when I actually trying to start a torrent. It crashes with the following error:

> /home/user/Desktop/build/ui/../bin/app: symbol lookup error:
> /home/user/Desktop/build/ui/../bin/libdownloadsbt.so.6: undefined
> symbol: TLS_client_method

In my `Qt` project this looks so:

```
LIBS += -Lpath_to_my_openssl/prebuilt/linux/lib
LIBS += -lcrypto -lssl
```

The second line is all the difference.

What is going on?

P.S. Works fine under `Windows` and `macOS`.

Comment: `-L` adds a path where the linker looks for libraries. The `-l` (lower-case L) option tells the linker to link with the specified library. The libraries specified by `-l` are searched for in the paths added by `-L`.

Comment: I know this. How does this answer my question? If you are able to read questions, you would notice that I know it :)

Comment: Please create a [mre] to show us. Of both the code and the Qt `.pro` file.

Comment: It's too heavy task for me. I would prefer to not do it. For now I have a workaround. This question is for the people which knows what can go wrong. Maybe some passing by guy will be able to write something useful for me, so I do not have to spend much time. :)

Comment: It's probably easier for you to do it than for us and it's probably more in your interest.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I agree, but maybe it's not required. Let's see :)

Comment: At least do a verbose build, where you can see all commands being executed. Look at the command doing the linking, what options, flags and *libraries* is given when linking? Also remember that *order matters* when linking.

Comment: One idea: After you've compiled the working version, do `ldd /home/user/Desktop/build/bin/app | sort > ~/working` then build the non-working version and do `ldd /home/user/Desktop/build/bin/app | sort > ~/nonworking` and finally do `diff ~/working ~/nonworking` to see the difference in the shared object files. The lines coming from `working` will be prepended by `<` and the lines coming from `nonworking` will be prepended by `>`

Comment: In second case you are likely picking up your ssl libraries when linking but system binaries at runtime. `TLS_client_method` was added relatively recently, in 2019. It doesn't explain why first case is working,though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all guys for the comments and help. The reason was the order of the libraries. Under Linux, their linking order matters.

So, this works fine:

```
-ltorrent-rasterbar -lcrypto -lssl
```

This crashes at runtime:

```
-lcrypto -lssl -ltorrent-rasterbar
```